# How can I shutdown a Raspberry Pi when HDMI is disconnected?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, systemd, raspberry-pi-zero

I would like run a service that automatically shuts down my RPi Zero as soon as the HDMI cable gets disconnected (this usually happens by unplugging the cable from the monitor).

So far I run this as a system.d service:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Airplay Server
tvservice -p
/home/administrator/RPiPlay/build/rpiplay -n Airplay -l -b auto -a hdmi &

#Check regularly if HDMI cable is disconnected and shut down in that case
while [ 1 ]
        do
                if ( tvservice -s | grep -c 0x9 ); then
                        echo "turning off"
                        shutdown now
                fi
                #sleep for x seconds and check again
                sleep 2
        done
```

But it feels hacky and I think, rather `tvservice -M` should be used. Unfortunately, I did not figure out how to leverage tvservice events by calling a script that shuts the RPi down.

Do you have an idea or can confirm that this code is resource efficient? I need to squeeze as much performance for the airplay service as possible and do not want to waste too much on these kind of background services.

Comment: can't say about resources except that a 2 second sleep seems very short. Changing it to 10 seconds will reduce the load of your script,possibly measurably. (?) An interesting problem, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, I can imagine. My challenge is that I want it to shut down quickly after monitor disconnect, because I want to shut off a whole power strip after finishing my AirPlay session on my couch. It comes together with my hifi and other audio/TV equipment which is not supposed to remain in stand-by mode. Especially my family will not have the patience to wait for 10sec and then another 2-5 for RPi shutdown :/

Comment: you may not need `| grep -c '0x9'`. Note that `if ( ...) ; then` is launching a subshell, which you don't need. Try `if tvservice -s ; then echo shutting down ; ... ; else ....; fi` instead. Also check your code at https://shellcheck.net . I don't really know about the services, so I'm just commenting on what I see as a shell programmer. Good luck.

Comment: as in linux everything is a file there should be a file descriptor somewhere which you can watch with [incron](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab). must be something in */dev /sys* or */prog* (like */sys/class/display/display0.hdmi/connect* for android) https://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained

Comment: Another option, ... upgrade to a Rpi 3b+ or other, but as you don't seem to have any problems, maybe everything is OK. A $10 machine dedicated to this seems like a reasonable engineering decision. Good luck.

Comment: You need a udev rule/trigger for detecting change in `drm` subsystem and running a script, in which you have to check for `/sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status`. Relevant linkt: https://frdmtoplay.com/i3-udev-xrandr-hotplugging-output-switching/

Comment: @andreoss that looks even better!

Comment: @andreoss : Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it. Good luck to all.

Comment: @andreoss : Your comment looks extremely usful. Unfortunately, 'udevadm monitor' does not show any events when plugging or unpluggin the HDMI cable. Also no error messages or other hints. Might be a special case on the Raspberry Pi..?

Comment: @DaCapitalist the specifics of rpi could come into play. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md, `hdmi_drive`, could it be that your HDMI port is operating in DVI mode? It appears there's no problem of using udef rules on rpi https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61764/writing-udev-rules-for-3g-usb-dongle